# Replace certain numbers and letters in multi-numbered, multi-lettered cells in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, replace

My dataframe in R includes specific `Patient_IDs` that I need to change for data safety reasons.

They are all named with the first letter of their last name and a six-digit number corresponding to their birth date (e.g., `A010590`). I could only find functions in R that replace the whole value (i. e., the whole package `"A010590"` to `"X"` for example), but I would like to change within each cell the letter to another letter (e.g., A to K) and the numbers to different numbers (e.g., 1 to 5) for all patients, i.e. in all rows of this "Patient_ID" column. (e.g., `A010190` would then become `K252132`, if A->K, 0->2, 1->5, 5->1, 9->3)

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: "For data safety reasons" can mean different things. Are there regulatory requirements you need to comply with? For a simple way to remove the personal information without being trivially reversible, I would suggest e.g. `hash <- digest::digest2int(df$Patient_IDs) ; paste0(LETTERS[hash %% 26 +1], substr(hash, 1, 6))`. Whether this is compliant remains entirely up to you.

Comment: I need to send data on patients to a university with such anonymous patient IDs but the crucial thing is that I would need to be able to transform the IDs back to our original (birth date) IDs if they would send them back at some point later to us. I am not sure I understand what your operation does to the ID. In itself it worked well, thank you. But now I am wondering if I would be able to translate these IDs back to their original ones. Do you know what I mean? I thought replacing each letter and number with a defined other letter or value would ensure that I'll be able to transform it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed`:

```r
library(stringi)

pattern = c("A", "0", "1", "5", "9")
replacement = c("K", "2", "5", "1", "3")
stri_replace_all_fixed("A010590", pattern, replacement, vectorize_all = FALSE)

# [1] "K212132"
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! However, as can be seen from your output "K212132" which should be "K252132", it seems that here the 1 is first transformed to 5 and then from 5 to 1 again. Any idea how to circumvent this problem?

Comment: That's right. You could do two separate steps.

Comment: How would that look like? I can't find a way to change all prior 1s  to 5s and 5s to 1s - in the end I always get either only 1s or only 5s.

Comment: update: I made it work by using lowercase letters and !"§$%&/()= instead of  ABC.... and 1234567890 and then transformed them back into uppercase letters and real numbers respectively. Thanks again!